# Why don't we set initial hidden states in RNN to random small numbers like we do to the weights?

Tags: python, deep-learning, rnn

I'm following a couple of tutorials on RNNs and the instructor said that we should always set the initial hidden state in our RNNs to a tensor of all zeros and I couldn't really understand why. Even when I looked online, it said that **fixing the hidden state to zero is a common choice and that this has been shown to force the RNN to focus on the input sequence regardless of the initial choice of the hidden state**. What do they mean by that exactly?

Comment: setting initial hidden states to random values roughly means the RNN is at a random state in time and not in an initial state (where previous hidden states would be zero), right?